# In ASP.NET MVC3 controllers, where do you instantiate your DataContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In your ASP.NET MVC 3 applications that use a [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) or [DbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28VS.103%29.aspx), where do you instantiate your data access object?

Here is a non-exhaustive list of where I've seen it done:

- Individually within each method of the controller
- In the controller's constructor
- As a property (lazy-initialized) of the controller
- In an ActionFilter, shoved into ViewBag
- In Global.asax Application_BeginRequest
- In an HttpModule

I can't identify a clear front-runner amongst all of those. What's worse, whenever I start a brand-new project, I tend to change it up, *just because*.

Does anyone have any battle-tested advice?

Answer (score 7):

My dependency injection framework controls the creation and lifetime of the DbContext. The instantiation usually happens when the controller (or one of its dependencies) is instantiated.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't find that particularly helpful. Ceding responsibility to a framework, and not knowing when the framework actually actually instantiates the object, doesn't seem like an answer (to me).

Comment: @Portman: Not sure what you mean. The DI container does exactly what I tell it to do through configuration rules. I said "usually" because the configuration and structure of my applications varies. In the simplest case of a controller directly dependent on the DbContext, it **will** be instantiated just before the controller. However, I often delegate data access to other services, and in that case the DbContext will be instantiated when these services need it.

Comment: Do you have an example of your config? If you have other services dependent on DbContext, how do you ensure that the DbContext is destroyed at the end of the request?

Comment: The MVC setup for Autofac is here: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Mvc3Integration. Any dependencies registered to the HttpRequest Lifetime scope will be disposed when the request ends.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I store it in `HttpContext.Items`, instantiating it the first time it is required, and re-using it if it is needed again. The lifespan of `HttpContext.Items` is the lifetime of the web request, so when all work for the request is complete, the data context is finished with.

I got the idea from story three in [this blog post by Steven Sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/29/linq-to-sql-the-multi-tier-story/), which also has some neat advice for extending that idea with inversion of control so there is no hard dependency between your data layer and `HttpContext`.

Comment: That just sounds hacky and wrong.

Comment: @George Stocker: Not that hacky or wrong if you aren't going the IoC route. Shouldn't access it directly all over the place from there, but it is the right backing store -- it is what most IoC containers use at the end of the day.

Comment: @George: the implementation seems hacky and wrong? Or the outcome? The outcome to me seems optimal: one, and one only, data context per web request. And the implementation, while it's a little fiddly  like IoC always is, effectively does the job of preventing the data layer from needing to know anything about web requests. Will you be providing the OP with an alternative approach?

Comment: Two words: Unit Testing.

Comment: Two words, create your own HTTPRequest helper. This is very common approach when your unit testing sesssion base information. You obviously haven't been doinig too much unit testing. :)

Comment: hacky and wrong, I kinda trust approaches from microsoft employees and which actually works really well. For one your only using one connection per-request and is easier to manage.

Comment: @George: nope, you'll have to elaborate on those two words. This approach (read the blog post describing it) is explicitly designed with IoC in mind to allow unit testing, the `HttpContext.Items` store is used when the code is running as part of a website, an alternative store is used when running in another environment, e.g. a unit test

Answer (score 1):

For smaller projects I [Basically, store it in HttpContext.Items](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/62126/35368).  However, I love lazying loading, so I'm not a fan of spinning up a DBContext on literally every HttpApplication Request.  So instead I wrote the following:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static MyDBContext MyDBContext(this Controller instance)
    {
        MyDBContext result = 
          instance.HttpContext.Items[typeof(MyDBContext).Name] as MyDBContext ;

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = new MyDBContext ();
            instance.HttpContext.Items[typeof(MyDBContext).Name] = result;
        }

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("No DBContext in HttpContext.");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This means I have a Strongly-Typed, Lazy loaded, Single DBContext per Request, MyDBContext available for any controller to use.

```
public HomeController
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    List<string> model = this.MyDBContext().Cars
                                           .Select(x => x.Name)
                                           .ToList();

    this.View(model);
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you Dispose of the DbContext after the HttpContext has ended?

Comment: You can do it manually by implementing the [global.asax Application_EndRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4923804/209259), or [don't dispose of it](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx).

Comment: Wouldn't there be issues with thread affinity and the fact that DbContext isn't thread safe?

Comment: It may be a static function, but the storage of the DBContext is in the (assumed) thread safe HttpContext.Items which is a HttpContext per calling thread.  If one thread had access to another threads HttpContext, there would be bigger problems then thread problems (security).